# Cannot enable TPM in the kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, yocto, tpm

I'm building a machine with **Yoctoproject**. I need **TPM module** for some purposes but I can't enable it.

I tried this way:

> I ran `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel`, accessed **Device Drivers >
>   Character devices > TPM hardware support** and marked all options relate TPM.
>
> Then, I ran `bitbake -c savedefconfig virtual/kernel` to save the
>   config as `deconfig` file in the build directory of the kernel. I checked the file and TPM options was enabled.
>
> CONFIG_TCG_TPM=y
>
> CONFIG_HW_RANDOM_TPM=y
>
> I copied and added it for the next build.
>
> I run `bitbake core-image-minimal` again and booted by running
>   `runqemu`. I checked and the **/dev/tpm*** still didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling TPM support in the kernel is only part of the setup; you also need to provide access to either a real TPM or a TPM emulator.

If you have a real TPM which isn’t used by anything else, you can forward it to QEMU as follows:

```
runqemu qemuparams="-tpmdev passthrough,id=tpm0 -device tpm-tis,tpmdev=tpm0"
```

If you want to use [a TPM emulator](https://github.com/PeterHuewe/tpm-emulator) (there might be better emulators, that’s the first one I found), you need to set it up to emulate on a socket, then forward that socket to QEMU and use it for the TPM inside QEMU:

```
runqemu qemuparams="-chardev socket,id=chrtpm,path=/tmp/swtpm-sock -tpmdev emulator,id=tpm0,chardev=chrtpm -device tpm-tis,tpmdev=tpm0"
```

[The QEMU manual](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#TPM-device-options) provides more information on the topic.